# Retorno undefined

Tags: javascript, funções, return

O código em si esta funcionando, até onde eu acho, o problema é que eu não estou entendo o por que da minha função esta retornando **undefined**. É uma função simples que esta retornando o que eu realmente quero, mas eu realmente não entendi este **undefined**.

Segue o código:

```
var nomeAluno = ["Gabriel", "Joao", "Maria", "Joaquim", "Joana"];

var np1 = [10, 9.2, 7, 0, 10];

var np2 = [7, 10, 9, 3, 9.8];

function calculaMedia(nota1, nota2){
    return (nota1 + nota2) / 2;
}

function condicao(media){
    if(media >= 7){
        console.log("Aluno aprovado!");
    }else{
        console.log("Aluno reprovado");
    }
}

for (i in nomeAluno){
    media = calculaMedia(np1[i], np2[i]);
    console.log("Aluno, " + nomeAluno[i] + ", NP1: " + np1[i] + ", NP2: " + np2[i]
+ " Média: " + media + ", Condição: " + condicao(media) +"\n");
}
```

O que ele me retorna:
[image: resultado]

Comment: console.log dentro de um console.log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função não está retornando qualquer coisa, está imprimindo algo no console, mas pra que vai imprimir algo se quer que essa função resulte em algo pra imprimir? Então mude:

```js
var nomeAluno = ["Gabriel", "Joao", "Maria", "Joaquim", "Joana"];
var np1 = [10, 9.2, 7, 0, 10];
var np2 = [7, 10, 9, 3, 9.8];

function calculaMedia(nota1, nota2){
    return (nota1 + nota2) / 2;
}

function condicao(media){
    return media >= 7 ? "Aluno aprovado!" : "Aluno reprovado";
}

for (let i in nomeAluno) {
    let media = calculaMedia(np1[i], np2[i]);
    console.log("Aluno, " + nomeAluno[i] + ", NP1: " + np1[i] + ", NP2: " + np2[i] + " Média: " + media + ", Condição: " + condicao(media) +"\n");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/ReturnSomething.js).

Aproveitei pra melhorar algumas coisas, mas não melhorei tudo.